# .htaccess Redirect to HTTPS except subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect all none-https requests to https excepts requests to sub-domains. For example

```
http://example.com/  =>  https://example.com/
http://example.com/page  =>  https://example.com/page
```

But

```
http://m.example.com/  REMAINS  http://m.example.com/
```

This is what I have in my .htaccess, which redirects all requests (including sub-domians):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I know that I have to add a condition before the RewriteRule but I am quite not sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add another `RewriteCond` before your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=m.example.com
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for all subdomains, instead of listing the URLS?

Answer (score 4):

To Exclude any Subdomain from https rewrite add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=/(.*?)/.example.com
```