# Force SSL HTTPS for subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have this code for forcing SSL on a website generally:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Which I got from [here](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/05/27/redirecting-to-https-in-laravel-5/)

I would like it to **only apply to a specific sub-domain**.

For example, if you were to visit `http://sub.domain.org` it should redirect to `https://sub.domain.org`.

I have a hunch that I need to add another `RewriteCond` which basically says *is the domain that is being hit is http://sub.domain.org*, but I am at a loss on how to write this code.

I've been looking at other stackoverflow questions such as:

[Force HTTPS and WWW for domain and only HTTPS for subdomains HTACESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894947/force-https-and-www-for-domain-and-only-https-for-subdomains-htacess)

[Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

and the Apache docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

And I've had these attempts:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(reports\.)?uksacb\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Sort of reversed the answer in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789598/htaccess-redirect-to-https-except-subdomain):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =reports.uksacb.org
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However I'm still failing to make sense of how to do it correctly.

If anyone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong, what I need to do to get it right and how does one go about debugging their rewrite conditions and rules to make sure it works properly I'd be very grateful. Sometimes I think my browser is caching the rules I've written and my different attempts are not taking any affect!

My whole `.htaccess` looks like this:

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =reports.uksacb.org` should work. Clear your browser cache and retest with that condition in 2nd rule

Comment: @anubhava Right will give that a shot and see how it goes thanks!

Comment: If you have a valid certificate for a subdomain that will by extension be valid for the main domain so simply set all domains/sub domains as TLS secured.

Answer (score 18):

To avoid using the domain or subdomain names I used to use the following code:

```
  # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I prefer without WWW.

**%{HTTPS}** Set to on if the request is served over SSL.

**%{HTTP_HOST}** Everything between the protocol (http:// or https://) and the request (/example-file.txt).

**%{REQUEST_URI}** Everything after the server address — for example, a request to http://example.com/my/example-file.txt sets this value as my/example-file.txt.

**%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}** The protocol used when the URL was requested — set to http or https.

I hope it can be useful for anybody.

Comment: I spent far too long trying to find a solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For debugging I use a website I found https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Using the rules you provided

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I got an error at

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

This might work for you

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]
```

Found the above example at https://www.sslshopper.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html

Comment: The first webpage is not active anymore

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that one yet